# Software other than paint to create parsetrees automagic

Tags: parsing, drawing, bnf

I have a BNF grammar, and quite a few expressions that I am suppose to parse in regard to the grammar. Does it exists some software that I can enter the trees using ( ) to express the tree and than the software draws them?

Comment: What do you mean "using ( ) to express the tree"?

Comment: He means encoding the tree as a set of nested S-expreesions: (+ (* A 3) (- X Y))

Comment: Yes, something like that! Thank you hehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wont draw your trees directly, but [Dot](http://www.graphviz.org/) comes pretty close. It really wants a graph, not a nested structure.

You can get there easily:
You can relatively easily explode your tree into a set of nodes with unique names, with child references being implemented using those unique references.  Now your tree is just a set of nodes with named references.   At that point it should be pretty easy to shape your node set so Dot will draw them for you.  Read the "dotguide" at the site for more details.